# Highcharts - Column/bar chart with target lines

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Using [highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/), what would be the best way to implement target lines over a column or bar chart? (Also known as target vs goal)

Found this picture from a similar d3.js thread as an example:
[image]

I'm thinking another series, but don't see any options in the documentation about a target line. Here's a basic column chart: jsfiddle.net/eksh8a8p/

I've thought about using a columnrange series, but you are limited to having a start/end value which can be problematic due to scaling of number values.

Are there other ideas/options that could create a similar result to the picture above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a columnrange series but there is a simpler option - a scatter series with a rectangle marker

```
    //custom marker
    Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols['c-rect'] = function (x, y, w, h) {
       return ['M', x, y + h / 2, 'L', x + w, y + h / 2];
    };

    //series options
    {
      marker: {
        symbol: 'c-rect',
        lineWidth:3,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        radius: 10
      },
      type: 'scatter'
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eksh8a8p/1/

Comment: Excellent. This solves my issue. I realized simply changing the "column" config to "bar" also rotates the target lines. Very useful.

Comment: Hi @morganfree, thx for your answer. I managed to use it on stacked column. do we know how to make the size of the scatter dynamic like the size of the column bar when it's displayed on different screen size?